# Creating custom plugin for tinymce

Tags: joomla-3.x, tinymce

I'm trying to create my own character counter plugin for the tinymce editor in Joomla 3, which would look exactly like the wordcount plugin. I already have the javascript code for the plugin, and this file is saved in its own folder in "/media/editors/tinymce/plugins/nameofplugin/". Following [this](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin) tutorial I should add it to the tinymce.init as a plugin option inside the "/media/editors/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" but I don't find the tinymce.init field in there. 
Also I doubt if I should create a  for the Character count label, but I don't know how to modify the article html file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not TinyMCE expert, looking into the unminified version of `tinymce.min.js` I would say all plugins are loaded automatically (with themes and languages) if they follow the convention of storing them under `plugins` directory:

`/plugins/{plugin_name}/plugin.min.js`

Here is the piece of code I think is responsible for loading:

```
function t() {
    var e = m.ScriptLoader;
    if (r.language && "en" != r.language && !r.language_url && (r.language_url = n.editorManager.baseURL + "/langs/" + r.language + ".js"), r.language_url && e.add(r.language_url), r.theme && "function" != typeof r.theme && "-" != r.theme.charAt(0) && !S.urls[r.theme]) {
        var t = r.theme_url;
        t = t ? n.documentBaseURI.toAbsolute(t) : "themes/" + r.theme + "/theme" + o + ".js", S.load(r.theme, t)
    }
    w.isArray(r.plugins) && (r.plugins = r.plugins.join(" ")), A(r.external_plugins, function(e, t) {
        T.load(t, e), r.plugins += " " + t
    }), A(r.plugins.split(/[ ,]/), function(e) {
        if (e = L(e), e && !T.urls[e])
            if ("-" == e.charAt(0)) {
                e = e.substr(1, e.length);
                var t = T.dependencies(e);
                A(t, function(e) {
                    var t = {
                        prefix: "plugins/",
                        resource: e,
                        suffix: "/plugin" + o + ".js"
                    };
                    e = T.createUrl(t, e), T.load(e.resource, e)
                })
            } else T.load(e, {
                prefix: "plugins/",
                resource: e,
                suffix: "/plugin" + o + ".js"
            })
    }), e.loadQueue(function() {
        n.removed || n.init()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already have my plugin inside that folder but nothing happens. Not even the "Character> " string prints. Do you think there should be something else done?

Comment: I am not sure, seems that you should add it also to TinyMCE plugins parameters to enable. See Editor - TinyMCE plugin. But it requires to modify XML-manifest for this plugin.

Comment: You are totally right! By adding the folder to the plugins folder and modifying the xml manifest file the plugin is done! Thank you!!

Comment: The bad side of this that XML-manifest could be reverted on next CMS update...

Comment: Ouch! Hadn't thought about that. Is there some way to make it, lets say "stable", or will I have to modify the manifest file once in a while?

Comment: Hmm, can you try to use "Custom Plugin" field in Editor - TinyMCE settings? I found this in the code:  
`$custom_plugin = $this->params->get('custom_plugin', '');`  `$plugins[] = $custom_plugin;`

Seems that you should write your plugin name there and it will be loaded.

Comment: If you add it this way there is no need to write anything in the manifest file

Comment: So it worked? "Custom Plugin" field?

Comment: Perfect! I have now two different plugins working, with their own folder and their name inside the custom plugin field. Thats all it takes.

Comment: Two? :) How is that? As I understand you can enter only one custom plugin name in this field?

Comment: Thats what I thought too, but if you put several plugin names just separated by a blank space they will work.