# Shortcut to insert non breaking space in TinyMCE?

Tags: plugin, editor, joomla3.8, tinymce

I'm using Joomla and it's integrated TinyMCE editor. I would like to use a shortcut like shift+space or ctrl+shift+space to insert a non breaking space fast and simple instead of to have to click a button in the toolbar.

I've found a blog article from Ryan Pollard about adding shurtcuts in TinyMCE. But I don't know, where I have to add the code.

I'm not a programmer. Could you help me to add this shortcut?

Thanks in advance

Best regards, Andreas

Answer (score 1):

**You have to write a TinyMCE Plugin:**

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/

**And use the TinyMCE-Api to inject your shortcut:**

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.shortcuts/

**How to add your plugin to TinyMCE:**

[Creating custom plugin for tinymce](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10740/creating-custom-plugin-for-tinymce)